# MSI BIOS Distorted

Tags: windows, windows-10, motherboard, bios, windows-installer

I just recently built my PC and normally installed windows. During the process, I thought that it's just normal that the boot logo of MSI is enlarged and pixelated. But even after installing all necessary drivers for the motherboard and GPU, it still remains the same. What's more is in the MSI BIOS Setup, almost all characters are on front of each other and after a few clicks, it just crashes so force shutdown. MSI Logo becomes distorted. It's as if something is corrupted but Im not sure. Moreover, my PC sometimes boots to a black screen after the MSI Logo.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What you have experienced is not normal.  You are either dealing with bad hardware or corrupt firmware.

Comment: It could also be a graphics card issue. Do you have on-board/integrated graphics that you could possibly use to see if these glitches still occur?

Comment: Flash the BIOS again to be sure it's not BIOS corruption.

Comment: @harrymc will do. Hopefully will work T_T

Comment: But what's weird is it's working fine after the boot screen. Also, the GPU does not provide the resolution automatically, had to add the resolution manually. I've read about CRU but the Nvidia panel provides the same functionality. Maybe the graphics card is really faulty?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, I thought it's just normal and only needs few updating/configures.  At least now I'm sure something's faulty here. Maybe I'll try updating the firmware for this, I noticed it's quite outdated.

Comment: @SamForbis unfortunately, my CPU (Ryzen 5 3600) does not have an integrated graphics card.

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw Just another tip, if it is the graphics card, you may be able to re-seat it or move it to a different slot to see if that helps. Sometimes the PCIe interface between the two can cause glitches like this. I agree with the others who say to try to update the BIOS as well. If you have another GPU laying around or a friend who is willing to let you borrow theirs to test, that would be a good idea as well.

Comment: @SamForbis, thank you! I'll try that as well, maybe after work. Im quite afraid of updating bios due to many troubles it brings to other users who update theirs as well. Maybe updating BIOS will be my last option. Thank you! I will update you later.